# Continental Pilsner Malt

Tags: ingredients, malt

What does the term "continental" mean when referring to malts?
I have seen that term used before, mainly when sourcing pilsner malt.
Is it just a different way of saying pilsner malt that has been grown and malted in Europe?
Maybe I am way off base.  I can get domestic Pilsner malt, so I assume "continental" means *not domestic*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continental means that the malt came from The Continent - Europe.

[Definition](http://www.google.com/search?q=define:continental): *of or pertaining to or typical of Europe; "a Continental breakfast"*